# As a result of rendering animation with Blender3.4, the image flickers. How do I fix this?

Tags: rendering, animation

I made an animation of about 5 seconds with Blender 3.4.
Rendering with Cycles. Video flickering? and the image will not be smooth.
How do I fix this? You can see the animation from the link below.

[See the rendered result on Youtube](https://youtu.be/42cxCJlE45s)

The image below shows the settings when rendering this animation. Waves flicker and are not smooth, especially in unguided animations.

Cycles Render Device
[image: Cycles Render Device]

Output Render properties
[image: Output Render properties]

RebderProperties
[image: RebderProperties]

ViewLayerProperties
[image: ViewLayerProperties]

DomainSetting01
[image: DomainSetting01]

WaterSetting
[image: WaterSetting]

The boat object has a main boat mesh, a collision mesh, and a guide mesh,
all of which have very few polygons.

Also, both the water material and the boat material are created with very simple nodes.
(Since the fluid shim puts a load on the PC, I tried not to put any more load on it.)

Please let me know if you have any improvements, such as setting the output.

Best regards